# Alterar dinamicamente o src de um iFrame

Tags: javascript, html

Posso trocar o `src` de um iframe por um valor qualquer? Isto é possível?

```
document.getElementById('idIframe').src = "www.google.com"
```

Comment: Chance url? **src** is img and **href** is location. `document.querySelector('img#idIframe').src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png"`

Comment: Claro que pode. Você tentou?

Comment: Sim... É normal isso acontecer

Comment: Porque fazer alteração dinamicamente? Qual a vantagem em fazer isso? Se colocar o src diretamente no iframe não vai economizar código?

Answer (score 1):

Como estás a fazer é correto. Tens de ter em atenção duas coisas:

- alguns urls não abrem dentro de iframes por [proteção de CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129), que impede assim manipular a página dentro de uma iframe
- o `src` tem de ser um url válido. Ou colocas um url relativo (como no exemplo que dei) ou colocas um endereço completo com `http://`

**Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/2a37sbrp/**